# what is the minimum radius of query for geofire?

Tags: firebase, geofire

What is the minimum radius we can query for, using geofire? The documentation does not state any minimum radius, and even there is an issue opened in their github repo stating the same question, but no one replied.

Answer (score 0):

Geofire hasn't put any limits on the radius queried as far as I know but you might want to take into consideration the limits of the hardware/OS you're designing for. Have a look at this table by the [Geolocator plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) showing limits on the platforms it works on
[image: location accuracy image]